# Two INSERT INTO statements for the same row SQL/php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying so hard and I can't find a solution for this problem.
I have two different INSERT statements:

```
INSERT INTO `logList`(`User_ID`) SELECT `User_ID` FROM `userList` WHERE keyname='somevalue';
INSERT INTO `logList`(`ttime`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

If I execute them, they will of course insert 2 different rows. How can I make a single `INSERT` that returns only one row?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to assume that this is what you really want:

```
INSERT INTO logList (User_ID, ttime)
    SELECT User_ID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM userList
    WHERE keyname = 'somevalue';
```

I doubt you want two separate rows, one with the user and `NULL` for time and the other with `NULL` for user and a value of the time.

I should note that you can define the `loglist` so `ttime` is defaulted to the current timestamp on the insert.  The use of such defaults is described in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html).

If you did that, then:

```
INSERT INTO logList (User_ID)
    SELECT User_ID
    FROM userList
    WHERE keyname = 'somevalue';
```

would always set `ttime`.

Comment: Ok I have manage to solve, thank you very much.

But what about if instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` there was an actual variable?

`INSERT INTO logList (User_ID, ttime)
    SELECT User_ID, $variable
    FROM userList
    WHERE keyname = 'somevalue';`
note that `$variable` does not belong to `UserList` Thank you once again.

Comment: @Madeo . . . That's fine.  No problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you ask, you can do it in one single Insert:

```
INSERT INTO `logList`(`User_ID`, `ttime`)
    SELECT `User_ID`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM `userList`
    WHERE keyname='somevalue';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this command:

```
INSERT INTO `logList`(`User_ID`) SELECT `User_ID` FROM `userList` WHERE keyname='somevalue';
INSERT INTO `logList`(`ttime`) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Which will create two rows and you want to create a single row. You can do that using a single command:

```
insert into loglist(USER_ID, ttime)
select User_ID, now()
from userList
where keyname = 'somevalue';
```

However, even though this is a solution, it is not a very elegant one. You should `alter loglist` and modify `ttime` to have the `default` value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and then you can simplify your `insert` command like this:

```
insert into loglist(USER_ID)
select User_ID
from userList
where keyname = 'somevalue';
```

this should be the normal behavior, since your `loglist` table should probably have the timestamp of the insertion moment anyway.